# JMESPath filter for elements with nested values starting with certain string

Tags: json, jmespath

I have the following JSON structure:

```json
[
    {
        "stack": [
            "datasync"
        ],
        "env": [
            "dev",
            "test"
        ],
        "runOnBranch": [
            "feature/",
            "bugfix/",
            "develop"
        ]
    },
    {
        "stack": [
            "datasync"
        ],
        "env": [
            "val",
            "prod"
        ],
        "runOnBranch": [
            "main"
        ]
    }
]
```

And I would like to filter the list based on if a given string starts with one of the strings defined in the `runOnBranch` attribute.

My best guess so far doesn't work:

```
[?runOnBranch.starts_with(@, `feature/`) == `true`]
```

The error I get is:

> "Search parse error": TypeError: starts_with() expected argument 1 to be type 2 but received type 3 instead.

The result I would like to get is:

```json
[
    {
        "stack": [
            "datasync"
        ],
        "env": [
            "dev",
            "test"
        ],
        "runOnBranch": [
            "feature/",
            "bugfix/",
            "develop"
        ]
    }
]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your attempt does not work because `starts_with` needs a string (`boolean starts_with(string $subject, string $prefix)`), while you are passing an array to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assess that there is one element in the array that starts with something you will need to:

1. assess each string in the array, effectively creating a list of boolean, so, with `starts_with` but targeting each string, not the whole array:

   ```
   runOnBranch[].starts_with(@, `feature/`),
   ```
2. assess that there is at least one true value contained in the resulting array, with the help of the [`contains` function](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#contains)

   ```
   contains(runOnBranch[].starts_with(@, `feature/`), `true`)
   ```
3. and finally put all this in your filter

So, we end with the query:

```
[?contains(runOnBranch[].starts_with(@, `feature/`), `true`)]
```

Which yields:

```json
[
  {
    "stack": [
      "datasync"
    ],
    "env": [
      "dev",
      "test"
    ],
    "runOnBranch": [
      "feature/",
      "bugfix/",
      "develop"
    ]
  }
]
```

And to be more coherent in notation, this can also be written as:

```
[?(runOnBranch[].starts_with(@, `feature/`)).contains(@, `true`)]
```

---

*Side note: simplify those kind of filter:*

```
[?runOnBranch.starts_with(@, `feature/`) == `true`]
```

*to*

```
[?runOnBranch.starts_with(@, `feature/`)]
```

*as `starts_with` already returns a boolean, as documented in the function signature:*

```
boolean starts_with(string $subject, string $prefix)
```

<sup>*Source: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#starts-with*</sup>

Comment: What can I say... great explanation! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Filter the list on attribute's `runOnBranch` any item starts with a given string."***

A: Put the below declarations into the *vars*

```yaml
_query: '[?runOnBranch[?starts_with(@, `feature/`)]]'
result: "{{ data|json_query(_query) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
result:
  - env: [dev, test]
    runOnBranch: [feature/, bugfix/, develop]
    stack: [datasync]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    data:
      - env: [dev, test]
        runOnBranch: [feature/, bugfix/, develop]
        stack: [datasync]
      - env: [val, prod]
        runOnBranch: [main]
        stack: [datasync]

    _query: '[?runOnBranch[?starts_with(@, `feature/`)]]'
    result: "{{ data|json_query(_query) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

---

You can put the string into a variable. For example,

```yaml
    pattern: feature/
    _query: '[?runOnBranch[?starts_with(@, `{{ pattern }}`)]]'
```

Then, you can override the string on the command line. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e pattern=ma

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  feature|to_yaml: |-
    - env: [val, prod]
      runOnBranch: [main]
      stack: [datasync]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```